# Magento > Join attribute from another product

Tags: php, mysql, magento, entity-attribute-value

In the admin product grid, I would like to join a field from another product. Let's say, some products have an attribute `reference_id`. I would like the added column to display the product type ID of the product, whose `entity_id` is the row's `reference_id`. This is what I ended up with so far:

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect($referenceAttributeCode)
    ->getSelect()->join($collection->getTable('catalog/product'), 'e.entity_id=at_'.$referenceAttributeCode. '.value', array('type_id' => 'reference_product_type'));
```

The problem here seems to be that when manipulating the `select` object, changes happen immediately, whereas changes made with `addAttributeToSelect()` take effect before the collection loads, and the resulting query looks like this:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_qty`.`qty`, `at_status`.`value` AS `status`, `at_visibility`.`value` AS `visibility`, `mgt_catalog_product_entity`.`type_id` AS `reference_product_type` FROM `mgt_catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `mgt_cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_qty` ON (at_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_qty.stock_id=1)
 INNER JOIN `mgt_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '96') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 0)
 INNER JOIN `mgt_catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '102') AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 0)
 INNER JOIN `mgt_catalog_product_entity` ON e.entity_id=at_product_reference.value
```

Of course, here `at_product_reference` does not exist, since the attribute has not yet been joined.

I'm probably doing it wrong. Any suggestions please? Much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You do not give the alias name to your table. So indeed this name do not exists at all

Comment: @dagfr, The table I join appears in the resulting query as it should, without any alias (see last line of MySQL query). It's the `at_product_reference` table that's not appearing.

Comment: INNER JOIN `mgt_catalog_product_entity` ON e.entity_id=at_product_reference.value should be INNER JOIN `mgt_catalog_product_entity` at_product_reference ON e.entity_id=at_product_reference.value. You have to add the alias

Comment: @dagfr, I am trying to join an attribute. From my example above you may see that I am calling `addAttributeToSelect()`. The argument to this function is `product_reference`, which is the name of the attribute I want to add. When Magento adds attributes to a collection's select, it joins it's value table aliased as `at_[attribute_code]`, which in this case should become `at_product_reference`. That is the table that's not there, not the product entity table.